# JBox2d TestbedMain.java "Selection does not contain a main type"

Tags: jbox2d

I have installed JBox2D through Maven on Eclipse Juno and in order to test the installation worked correctly, I am supposed to try running the TestbedMain.java but Eclipse keeps giving me the error "Selection does not contain a main type" and sometimes "Editor does not contain a main type".  I have tried closing and reopening both the project, the file and Eclipse and nothing has helped.  If anyone has any idea why this would be happening or how I could fix it, then I would be very happy to try.  I am also just getting around to learning Eclipse a bit more in depth so if there is something that is a more in depth step, please spell it out for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure you import all the projects as Maven project, so you should see 4 projects listed.  Then make sure you're right clicking on the testbed or testbed-jogl projects :)